# Is it possible to print a page with HTML5 (without JavaScript)?

Tags: html

I am creating a web page for a special browser, which does not support JavaScript, only HTML, how can I print the page without JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

Browsers provide no features for printing documents which are not triggered by:

- JavaScript
- The browser's own UI